# Replace word + xx (unknown ) value using c#

Tags: c#, file, replace, operation

I am trying to do the replace string in the file. I want to replace the word and xyz(unknown) value. Eg. My  .java file contains hello
hello01 
hello03
hello07 
hello09 
.
.
.
hello99
I want to replace helloXX to hello
The XX are random. How to do it using C#?

Comment: `var output = Regex.Replace("hello01 hello03 hello07 hello09 ", @"hello\d\d", "hello");`

Comment: @Eser Why not post that as an answer instead of a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be to use a Regex class

Edit:

```
        var regex = new Regex(@"hello\d+");

        var original = "hello123";
        var updated = regex.Replace(original, "hello");
```

Comment: It is a comment not an answer

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I want to open the .java file and replace all the old_value to new_value. Can you please explain me how to open .java file and do the replace.

Comment: .java files are stored as plain text. Just use a StreamReader to open the file: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx